# Weird inner geometry showing when I deform mesh in Pose Mode

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, geometry

My armature is working as normal except for the fact that there's a weird tube thing inside the geometry that only shows when I bend parts (in the image I'm bending it at the elbow and the tube starts to peek out.

[image]

Does anybody know how I can get rid of this?
:(

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There was hidden inside geometry. I just zoomed in, selected one of the faces of the tube, and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>L</kbd> to get all linked faced then deleted them.